# Cascading dripdown list in MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I have 3 tables country , state , city .

I want cascading drop down list as usual.

How can i do that without using the LINQ.

I don't know that how to start. I want to do that using RAZOR. It is okay if it is in JQUERY or JSON.

How to start that.

Thanks in advance.

Can i do that using stored procedure.

tables are:-

user:

name
cityid

country:

id stateid name

state

stateid cityid name

city

cityid name .

i have tried nothing because i don't know where to start.

Comment: Why not LINQ to filter your results?

Answer (score 2):

A general approach to creating cascading selects

Create a view model containing the properties you want to display, including properties for the country and state ID's and a SelectList for the Country options

In your view render selects using `@HtmlDropDownFor()` for the Country, Sate and Property ID's (the Country select will be populated; the others will be empty)

Using jQuery, in the Country change event, use an AJAX call to an action method which returns a list of States based on the selected Country (either return html to replace the City select, or return JSON to create a new set of option elements.

Repeat the above when a State is selected (to populate the City select)

Answer (score 0):

No one here will provide you complete code like you are asking in your question but usage of dropdown i m explaining below :

Basic and cleanest way to make a dropdown in MVC is like :

Model :

```
public List<SelectListItem> ItemTypes { get; set; }
public int ItemVal { get; set; }


In your [HttpGet] Controller just bind `Model.ItemTypes` with values
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemVal , new SelectList(Model.ItemTypes , "Value", "Text"), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

here in above example the 3rd overload of DropDownListFor() i.e. " `-----Select List-----` " will be the initial selected item of your dropdown with value equal to ' '.

At Controller during POST ItemVal will have selected dropdown value.

The above shown code is best and simplest way to bind Dropdownlist in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

See this exmple. You'll have an idea. I'm just showing sample which is not tested.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var countries = new List<string> { "USA", "India" };

        ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(countries);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetStates(string country)
    {
        //perform filter here based on country
        return Json(new[] {
            new { Id = 1, Value = "State 1" },
            new { Id = 2, Value = "State 2" },
            new { Id = 3, Value = "State 3" },
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View Page**

```
<div>Select country:</div>
<div>@Html.DropDownList("country",
                            ViewBag.Countries as SelectList,
                            "Please select",
                            new { id = "country" })
</div>
<div>Select state:</div>
<div>
    <select id="state"></select>
</div>
```

**On Country selection, do ajax call and get related states.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#country').on('change', function () {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetStates")', function (result) {
                var ddl = $('#state');
                ddl.empty();
                $(result).each(function () {
                    $(document.createElement('option'))
                        .attr('value', this.Id)
                        .text(this.Value)
                        .appendTo(ddl);
                });
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: hey i want using the stored procedure

Comment: It's not much different.  Use your call to your SP in GetStates and create a similar object as Ashwini did.